# merging comments from two comments plugin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, plugins, facebook-comments

It seems that we have pages in our application which have been using two different href values for the Facebook Comments plugin over time (this wasn't intentional and caused due to mis-configuration) and we are left with missing comments (comments made when the plugin was initiated with the older HREFs).

We can't go back to old hrefs, since people have been commenting on the new HREFs as well.

Given this background, I am looking for a way to merge two HREFs for the comments plugin through one of the following methods:

- Do a server side export from the old href and then re-importing it into the new href?
- Perhaps a way to initiate the FB comments plugin with two href params so that it automatically merges it at that end?

I know that I can get the old comments through Graph API, but I am also looking to insert it back into the current plugin so that the conversation is complete.

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reconnecting Facebook comments to another URL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7698813/reconnecting-facebook-comments-to-another-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible in reliable way...

Theoretically it's possible to re-submit old comments to the Graph API associating 'em with other/new URL, but there is some show-stoppers:

1. `BUG #216005175135629`: [Unable to post comments to social plugin via graph calls](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/216005175135629).
2. There is no way to specify time of the comment while submitting, so all the migrated comments will be dated with current time (instead of the original submission time)
3. You will need identity (`access_token`) for every person comments of whom you want to migrate, without that comments will be owned by user owning the active `access_token`